# Why is a float64 type number throwing int related error in Go

Tags: go

I am trying to grasp Golang, in one of the tutorial example it says that `An untyped constant takes the type needed by its context.`

```
package main

import "fmt"

const (
    // Create a huge number by shifting a 1 bit left 100 places.
    // In other words, the binary number that is 1 followed by 100 zeroes.
    Big = 1 << 100
    // Shift it right again 99 places, so we end up with 1<<1, or 2.
    Small = Big >> 99
)

func needInt(x int) int { return x*10 + 1 }
func needFloat(x float64) float64 {
    return x * 0.1
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(needInt(Small))
    fmt.Println(needFloat(Small))

    // Here Big is too large of a number but can be handled as a float64.
    // No compilation error is thrown here.
    fmt.Println(needFloat(Big))

    // The below line throws the following compilation error
    // constant 1267650600228229401496703205376 overflows int
    fmt.Println(Big)
}
```

When calling `fmt.Println(Big)` why is Golang treating `Big` as an `int` where as by context it should be `float64`?

What am I missing?

Comment: go does not do implicit casting. Big is a const initialized to a number, so it's type is fixed as an int. Therefore it cannot be directly used as a float parameter with some explicit type conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is the context for `fmt.Println`? In other words, what does `fmt.Println` expect `Big` to be? An `interface{}`.

From [the Go Blog on Constants](https://blog.golang.org/constants):

> What happens when fmt.Printf is called with an untyped constant is that an interface value is created to pass as an argument, and the concrete type stored for that argument is the default type of the constant.

So the default type of the constant must be an int. The page goes on to talk about how the defaults get determined based on syntax, not necessarily the value of the const.

Comment: Oh, I missed that, since it wasn't in the main part of the code.

Comment: But if `Big` is `int` type then how is it able to hold such a big number?

Comment: @Nagri, Big is a numeric constant not an int. You're thinking of it like a variable with a specific type, but it's not. When Big is used in a context that expects a float, then Big becomes a float. When used in another context that expects an int, then Big becomes an int.

Comment: @NathanSurfus, Thanks for explaining but I am still far from understanding this. Please bear with me. In the above example why does `fmt.Printf("%T", Small)` works but `fmt.Printf("%T", Big)` throws `constant 1267650600228229401496703205376 overflows int`? Cause `Big` and `Small` both are const.

Comment: When Big and Small are passed info fmt.Printf, the compiler needs fo figure out what type it should use when invoking fmt.Printf. Since fmt.Printf wants an interface{}, their default type of the const is used, which is int. Small fits inside the int type, but Big does not.

Answer (score 0):

`Big` in `fmt.Println(Big)` has type integer which is more than max int value `9223372036854775807`

you can find max int from this logic

```
const MaxUint = ^uint(0)
const MaxInt = int(MaxUint >> 1)
fmt.Println(MaxInt) // print 922337
```

2036854775807

To fix it, you need to cast it to float64 like this

```
fmt.Println(float64(Big))
```